# How can I initialise the generic collection in Java?

Tags: java

I have a function which returns a Collection of a class defined by me. I am in the process of writing Unit Test for this class, but, I can't wrap my head around initializing the collection or making a new one.
Following is the method:

```
public Collection<MyClass> getHistory(String id) {
    return infoRepository.findId(id);
}
```

Now, the UT for the following is as follows:

```
  public void testGetHistory () {
    String id = "Sample-Id";
    MyClass myclass1 = getMyClass();
    StackInfo myclass2 = getMyClass();
    Collection<MyClass> myClassCollection = null;
    myClassCollection.add(myclass1);
    myClassCollection.add(myclass2);
  }
```

In the UT, I have more stuff after this (Mockito, Assert statements) but I get an error when I try to add the instances of myclass to the collection. My code doesn't work. I understand that I am initialising it to NULL because of which it has a problem. But, how do I make a new collection then?

Comment: `Collection<MyClass> myClassCollection = new ArrayList<>()`, or whatever `Collection` implementation that is suitable for you

Answer (score 1):

Since Collection is an interface, you can't instantiate it, you have to initialize with a class that implements the Collection interface. That could be ArrayList, LinkedList, HashSet, etc...

```
Collection<MyClass> myClassCollection = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
Collection<MyClass> myClassCollection = new LinkedList<MyClass>();
Collection<MyClass> myClassCollection = new HashSet<MyClass>();
```

In the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) you can find the Java implementations of Collection in the "All Known Implementing Classes" section.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the collection to any type, that implements the Collection interface:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

For instance, an ArrayList :

```
Collection<MyClass> myClassCollection = new ArrayList<>();
```